# Java replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I was using `String.replaceAll(String, String)` when I noticed that replacing a string with `$` symbols around it would not work. Example `$REPLACEME$` would not be replaced in a Linux system. Anyone know why this is?

Some code:

```
String foo = "Some string with $REPLACEME$";
foo = foo.replaceAll("$REPLACEME$", "characters");
System.out.println(foo);
```

Output:

```
Some string with $REPLACEME$
```

Comment: Why are you using `replaceAll` rather than `replace`? Do you *need* regular expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is a special character that needs to be escaped:

```
foo = foo.replaceAll("\\$REPLACEME\\$", "characters");
```

Or more generally use `Pattern.quote` which will escape all metacharacters (special characters like `$` and `?`) into string literals:

```
foo = foo.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$REPLACEME$"), "characters");
```

Comment: Why does it need to be escaped?

Comment: It means end of a line in [regular expression syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). So unless you have an end of string at the start of your string...

Comment: +1 for `Pattern.quote`, I was already contemplating an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the `Pattern.quote`

Answer (score 3):

`replaceAll` uses a regular expression as its first argument. `$` is an anchor character that matches the end of a matching string in regex so needs to be escaped

```
foo = foo.replaceAll("\\$REPLACEME\\$", "characters");
```

Comment: I would also add that in pure regex, a literal dollar sign has to be escaped `\$`, but in Java the escape character has to be escaped, hence `\\$`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method uses [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), and the `$` character is a metacharacter in a regular expression that represents the end of the string. However, the [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method also replaces all instances of the target string with the replacement string, and uses an ordinary string, not a regular expression. This will do what you are expecting:

```
String foo = "Some string with $REPLACEME$";
foo = foo.replace("$REPLACEME$", "characters");
System.out.println(foo);
```